# How to select item from media library in Xcode 10 and put it to code

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I open library using cmd + shift + M, select something using arrows, but how am I supposed to put it to the code? The only way I found is to drag and drop it there, but it seems too inconvenient to me. Enter key doesn't work, so, is there something I'm missing all the time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Drag and drop form that list but it will make it as:

> #imageLiteral(resourceName: "some_resource.png")

Now, it depends what type of media you want to use and in what way.

For example if you have a image (same as the example)

```
let someImage = UIImageView()
someImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "some_resource.png") // should have beend dragged and dropped here
view.addSubview(someImage)
```

but this can also be written as:

```
let someImage = UIImageView()
someImage.image = UIImage(named: "some_resource.png") 
view.addSubview(someImage)
```

When using this shortcut (**⇧⌘M**) to search for items, you can add them by dragging.